# Jenkins Android Gradle build time download error

Tags: android, linux, jenkins, gradle, sudo

Linux environment using jenkins android gradle project to build an error

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not download glide.jar (com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0)
   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/bumptech/glide/glide/3.7.0/glide-3.7.0.jar'.
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/bumptech/glide/glide/3.7.0/glide-3.7.0.jar'.
         > repo.jfrog.org: unknown error

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I tried to use the wget way to download the link will prompt an error, then I use the sudo way to download the link successfully. So, how can I make jenkins gradle also use the sudo download, or use other solutions

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
        classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

    // Exclude the version that the android plugin depends on.
    configurations.classpath.exclude group: 'com.android.tools.external.lombok'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: The problem has been resolved, may be associated with the download permissions or way, gradle version replaced by the latest ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try upload your local library (in user/.gradle/caches) to Jenkins server, It 's work for me.

Comment: I uploaded the gradle after download or download error

Comment: @壹尘子 try add mavenCentral() in `project build.gradle`

Comment: @壹尘子 i think you need set some proxy in your country -- China

Comment: I have to rely on the local file upload to the cloud server, but how can I set to use gradle cache dependencies, as long as the use of jenkins build gradle or to re-download

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that run the build with super user rights is a good solution, because it's not seems to be possible to resolve dependencies.

Just a suggestion how to solve it: Gradle has it's own local cache for dependencies and doesn't need to download them on every build. So you may use the same Gradle distribution, which is used by Jenkins, and once build your application manually with su rights, to resolve all dependencies and cache them.

Just to note, by default dependencies with dynamic versions are cached for 24 hours only, as it's said in [the official docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:controlling_caching), but you can change it as:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheDynamicVersionsFor 10, 'minutes'
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 4, 'hours'
}
```

Comment: Although I use the sudo way to download success, but when I use jenkins to build the project Gradle or to re-download the dependencies, how to use gradle has been downloaded good cache dependency?